# Way to pass information from a GET parameter to a POST form in django?

Tags: django, post, django-forms, hidden-field, disabled-input

I have a mailing list system in which a user can click a link to unsubscribe. This link contains the user's email in a GET parameter and the page it points to contains a short form to ask for feedback. This feedback needs to point to the email of the user who submitted it.

The way I tried to achieve this is:

1. take the email from the GET parameter
2. put it as `initial` value in a hidden field on the feedback form
3. retrieve it from form data when the form is sent

The problem is that if this hidden field is not disabled, the user can meddle with its value and dissimulate his own identity or even claim that the feedback came from another user. But if I set the field as disabled, the request.POST dictionary does not contain the field at all.
I also tried keeping the field enabled and checking for its presence in `form.changed_data`, but it seems to always be present there even if its value does not change.

This is the form class:

```py
class UnsubscribeForm(forms.Form):
    reason = forms.ChoiceField(choices=UnsubscribeFeedback.Reasons.choices)
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)
    user_email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=False, disabled=False)
```

This is how I populate `user_email` in the view when the method is GET:

```py
email = request.GET.get("email", "")
# ...
context["form"] = UnsubscribeForm(initial={"user_email": email})
```

Note that I also tried disabling the field manually after this line, as well as in the form's init method. The result is the same: if the field is disabled, the value does not get passed.
After setting the initial value, I print()ed it to make sure it was being set correctly, and it is. I also checked the page's source code, which showed the value correctly.

And this is how I check for the value in the POST part of the view, when the data-bound form is being received:

```py
form = UnsubscribeForm(request.POST)

if form.is_valid():  # This passes whether I change the value or not.
    if "user_email" in form.changed_data:  # This too passes whether I change the value or not.
        print("Changed!")

    email = form.cleaned_data["user_email"]  # This is "" if user_email is disabled, else the correct value.
```

I have no idea why the initial value I set is being ignored when the field is disabled. As far as I know, a disabled field passes the initial value over regardless of any changes, but here the initial value isn't being passed at all. And as I outlined above, I can't afford to keep this field editable by the user, even if it's hidden.

Django is version 3.0.3, if that matters.

Any solution? Is this a bug?

Comment: Do you need the email field in your form at all? Wouldn't it be saver to fetch the email of the user in your view by using ```request.user.email```?

Comment: The user is not logged into the site, there is no login system in place, so the request itself doesn't by itself contain information about that.

Comment: I see. Checking for changed data only works if you provide initial data to the form instance, something like ```form = UnsubscribeForm(request.POST, initial={...})```. So you need the email in the post view. But then you do not need it in the form. In short: IMHO your approach will not work.

Comment: I don't need to check for changed data if I can pass that data through the initial data of a disabled input—that was my initial approach. Is there no way to retrieve that data at all? And if so, what use are hidden fields if they can only be used when the user can also meddle with them?

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative approach for my use case? I'm grasping at straws here, frankly...

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are looking for a way to pass a value from one view to the other in a way, that cannot be manipulated by the user. Disabled fields can easily be changed to enabled by the user so this method is not safe. A possible alternative is using django sessions to pass the email around. However, this can also be manipulated (although it is a little harder than just changing disabled fields).

Comment: I was counting on the fact that Django ignores modifications on fields it knows are disabled (based on the "blueprint" of the form, so the user changing this has no effect), which causes it to take their "initial value" regardless of any modification. That initial value can be set on form instantiation, which is what I tried to do, but it is apparently being ignored for disabled fields (but not enabled ones, for which it works well, but it invalidates their utility for my specific use case).

Comment: I'd use sessions but as you say, they can be modified by the user and I have no way to verify whether the user changed the information I put in it.

Comment: Not sure but would it be a possibility to add a hash token based on the email and a secret key to a to check?

Comment: Yes! In fact, that's exactly what I did to solve the problem (see my own answer below). It's still puzzling to me why my original approach wouldn't work, but at least I could solve the practical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, though it doesn't quite answer the question of why disabled fields ignore runtime initial values, so in a sense, the question is still open to answers.

In the original question, I crucially neglected to specify (in an effort to make the code minimal and reproducible) that the GET request that includes the user's email address also contains a token I generate with unpredictable data to verify that the email is authentic and corresponds to a subscribed user. In order to successfully meddle with the email, a user would also have to forge a valid token, which is unlikely (and not worth the effort) unless they have access to both my database and codebase (in which case I have worse problems than a feedback form).

I will simply keep the hidden field not disabled and also pass the token along, to verify that the address is indeed valid.